# Interactive Web Dashboards in R

Tags: r, business-intelligence, interactive, dashboard, shiny

Can we create a interactive dashboard in R and send the html link to "Non" R user?
If we can, can someone please let me know the process.

I know package "shiny" helps in creating a interactive dashboard, but the end user has to have R in his machine in order explore it.

Answer (score 8):

We have a Shiny application hosting service that is currently in beta ([register here](https://rstudio.wufoo.com/forms/shiny-server-beta-program/)).

Also in late January 2013 [we'll be releasing Shiny Server as open source](http://blog.rstudio.org/2012/12/04/shiny-update/), so you can run applications on your own Linux server (or in the cloud, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for dashboards and layouts with R.

- For making grids and combining plot types in R, ggplot2's [facet_wrap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) and [facet_grid](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_grid.html) are handy. To be able to share them with a URL, you can use the [plotly ggplot2 figure converter](https://plot.ly/ggplot2). For example, we can [install the library](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/getting-started/) then run this snippet:

```html
library(plotly)

dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)

py <- plotly()
py$ggplotly()
```

The response is a URL that you can make [public or private](https://plot.ly/r/privacy/). For example: https://plot.ly/~chris/2223/price-vs-carat/. The plot is drawn with D3.js and is interactive. You can embed, zoom, toggle, and see text on the hover from the browser. The person you're sending to doesn't need to have R or Shiny.

[image]

[These docs](http://ropensci.github.io/plotly-test-table/tables/0e3d5ca144d27d8416318824c1b6ec1421a51045/index.html) track coverage for the figure converter.

- As Joe noted, [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) allows you to make web apps and dashboards with R. You can connect to the [ggplot2 figure converter](https://plot.ly/ggplot2), make a graph in Shiny, then save the graph and share as a Plotly URL. Here is [a tutorial](http://moderndata.plot.ly/dashboards-in-r-with-shiny-plotly/) with code examples. Your published apps let you zoom, toggle, filter, pan, and see data on the hover, e.g.:


  [image]


  Disclaimer: I'm on the Plotly team.

Answer (score -2):

You don't create web pages in R, you create web pages in HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Can you create HTML, CSS, and Javascript from R? Yes.

Can you serve web pages from R? Yes.

R has a built-in web server for mainly serving the internal help pages, but you can graft applications onto it. There's also the 'rook' package for more sophisticated web applications.

Learn to write a "Hello World" page using rook, then get back to us. Otherwise this question is waaaay too broad, and you haven't done much research, and I'll vote to close it.